# Debian broken filesystem by chmod -R 0774 /

Tags: debian, permissions, chmod

An user made the chmod -R 0774 / command.
When i execute the su command i get:

```
"it was not possible to define groups".
```

If i try to ssh from the root i get:

```
/bin/bash permission denied
```

the permissions in /bin/bash are 0755

Comment: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/12998/wrongly-set-chmod-777-problems - please note that the accepted answer is blatantly wrong (and modded at -7 for this very reason). Personally, unless I was looking for a technical challenge, I would just reinstall. It would save time and be more or less the only way to be sure of all permissions being correctly reinstated.

Comment: After a while i was unable to solve it completely. Will reinstall the system and make a snapshot.Thanks for the reply